# php code for sending a mail using smtp

Tags: php

this is my code am not receiving any mail through this code.

```
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS[email];
$mailto ="nr.shubha@gmail.com"; 
$mailsubj = "Form submission"; 
$mailhead = "From: $email\n";
reset ($HTTP_POST_VARS); 
$mailbody = "Email form the web site form:\n";
echo $HTTP_POST_VARS; 
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($HTTP_POST_VARS)) { 
     $mailbody .= "$key : $val\n"; 
} 
if (!eregi("\n",$HTTP_POST_VARS[email])) { 
    mail($mailto, $mailsubj, $mailbody, $mailhead); 
}

print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS);
```

Comment: If you did not make mail settings correct mail() function will not work properly.

Comment: What is this code I don't even

Comment: **`error_reporting(E_INDIAN);`**

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to use premade classes like https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

It's much "spam safe" than using plain PHP code, and helps you with image embedding, attachments, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [PHPMailer Library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/master.zip). Works great.

Here is a sample of my work

```
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP

//This part is for authentication
$mail->Host = "mail.example.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = "SMTPAuth";     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "user@example.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "****"; // SMTP password

//the receiver will see that the sender address is this
$mail->From = "ihavesentit@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "The Sender";

//You can use AddAdress() and AddCC() functions several times for different receivers
$mail->AddAddress("receiver@example.com");
$mail->AddCC('another_receiver@example.com');

$mail->AddReplyTo("reply-to-me@example.com");

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters (arbitrary)

$mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "mail subject";

$mail->Body = "<p>mail content will be typed here</p>";

$mail->AltBody = "will be used if the receiver does not accept HTML content e-mails";

//final and the most important action
$mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Work only on the live server when it will host. It will not work on the localhost.

Because the SMTP only work on the live hosted server not on the "localhost".